# How do I add a catch on import-csv audit?

Tags: powershell

I have this script below and the input has more rows than the output. I assume it's because the import is technically an export from a system I audit that the script can't find in AD. How do I add a catch to notify me which can't be found in AD?

```
Import-Csv "C:\temp\users.csv" |
    %{  Get-AdUser -filter "name -like '$($_.Name)'" } | 
    Select Name, enabled | 
    Export-csv -path C:\temp\completeaudit.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Here is a sample of the input:

```
Name
Jane Doe
```

Here is a sample of Output:

```
Name    enabled
Jane Doe    TRUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to output the input, but to add a calculated property to each item. Here's an example of how you could do that:

```
Import-Csv "C:\temp\users.csv" |
    Select Name, @{l='Enabled';e={(Get-AdUser -filter "name -like '$($_.Name)'").Enabled}} |
    Export-csv -path C:\temp\completeaudit.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This would create your CSV with all of the input users shown, and those that got a response from AD would have True/False in the Enabled column, while anybody that was not found in AD would be blank.

You could obviously add more logic to check for blank results and fill in something, or throw a warning or something, but this is a pretty simple way to make sure all of the input is included in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a simple `if{}..else{}`:

```
Import-Csv "C:\temp\users.csv" |
    ForEach-Object {
        $nameToCheck = $_.Name
        $user = Get-AdUser -Filter "name -eq '$nameToCheck'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        # if the user could not be found, $user is $null
        if ($user) { 
            $user | Select Name, Enabled
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "User $nameToCheck could not be found.."
        }
    } | Export-Csv -path C:\temp\completeaudit.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>`-like` without wildcard characters will do the same as `-eq`. Also, names in AD are not unique, so it is always better to use properties like `DistinguishedName`, `UserPrincipalName` or `EmailAddress` for that</sup>